# Centraliser $Z(M,N)$ is commutative if and only if $Hom_N(W,Res_N(V)$ has simple multiplicities.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let M be a semisimple finite-dimensional C-algebra, and let N be its
subalgebra; the centralizer $Z(M,N)$ of this pair is the subalgebra of all elements of
$M$ that commute with $N$.
I already show that if $W$ is an irreductible representaion of $N$ and $V$ an irreductible representation of $N$. $Hom_N(V,W)$ is an irreductible $Z(M,N)$-module.
Now I would like to show that The restriction of any finite-dimensional irreducible complex representation of the algebra M to N has simple multiplicities only if the centraliser $Z(M,N)$ is commutative.
So if we assume that $Z(M,N)$ is not commutative, it has at least one irreductible representation of dimension $k \ge 2$. But now I don't see why this representation can be write as $Hom_N(W, Res_N(V))$.
Thanks for you help.